# Where does ntpdate get its settings from and what is the "no servers can be used" error about?

Tags: server, command-line, time, date, ntp

When I run `ntpdate` on its own, I get the following output:

> 8 Jun 15:47:46 ntpdate[31251]: no servers can be used, exiting

If I run it with the `-q ntp.ubuntu.com` switch, it seems to query just fine.

I have been hunting through many files and the most relevant one I have found is `/etc/default/ntpdate`, however, even with `NTPDATE_USE_CONF` set to no, I just can't understand/see how this error is occurring

Any ideas?

Update--

It appears that `ntpdate-debian`works fine and is the actual command that makes use of `/etc/default/ntpdate`, but this doesn't answer the main question and I still can't find it...

Comment: Unresolved in: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntp/+bug/176844

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After mucking around for most of the day, I have come to the following conclusion:

`ntpdate-debian` is the version to use if you want to use a config script, and in that case, you would edit the `/etc/default/ntpdate` file.

`ntpdate` cannot be used without arguments nor does it have a config file. If you want to use this to update, you have to state the ntp server in an argument, such as `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`.

Comment: I have two days left to accept my own answer... If no one else replies, I will accept this, but will happily switch over if you have anything better to add!

Comment: I wanted to know why/how ntpdate was called on boot. On Ubuntu 14, it looks like ntpdate-debian is run at boot when each network interface starts. See /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate. Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24827/72349.

Answer (score 1):

`NTPDATE_USE_NTP_CONF` refers to `/etc/ntp.conf` file as defined:

`Set to "yes" to take the server list from /etc/ntp.conf, from package ntp,
 so you only have to keep it in one place.`

Your error seems to be something temporary.

Comment: I am getting that error all the time, and, the file /etc/ntp.conf doesn't exist - I have tried a few different configs with the same result